# What is the longest set of consecutive matches a player has managed to score in Europe’s top 5 Leagues?

Tags: football, trivia, top-five

How many matches in a row has a football player managed to score in Europe’s Top 5 Leagues?

Comment: You might want to add a time frame to the question. Also are you looking for consecutive games the player played, or consecutive league games? That makes a difference if a player scores 5 games in a row, is rested due to injury one game, and then scores 5 games in a row again.

Comment: Using abbreviations in titles, especially those that are uncommon, especially where they are ungrammatical, does not increase quality.

Comment: Further, the inclusion of tags merely to fill out the limit, when this requires excluding tags which are equally applicable, is not likely to make them more searchable.

Comment: The question was about the player scoring in the top 5 leagues, So it would make sense to include those leagues in the tags as well? What's your point?

Answer (score 2):

## Bundesliga

[Gerd Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_M%C3%BCller) scored scored in 16 consecutive games in the [1969–70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1969%E2%80%9370_Bundesliga) season.

## La Liga

[Lionel Messi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi) scored in 21 consecutive matches in the [2012–13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012%E2%80%9313_La_Liga) season.

## Ligue 1

[Vahid Halilhodžić](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vahid_Halilhod%C5%BEi%C4%87) ([1984–85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984%E2%80%9385_French_Division_1)) and [Zlatan Ibrahimović](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlatan_Ibrahimovi%C4%87) ([2015–16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015%E2%80%9316_Ligue_1)) both scored in nine games in a row.

## Premier League

[Jamie Vardy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Vardy) holds record of scoring in 11 consecutive matches, he achieved this record in the [2015–16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015%E2%80%9316_Premier_League) season.

## Serie A

[Fabio Quagliarella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabio_Quagliarella) and [Gabriel Batistuta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Batistuta) share the record of scoring in 11 consecutive games.

## Sources

- Wikipedia articles of the individual players
- Wikipedia articles: [Bundesliga records and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesliga_records_and_statistics#Runs_2) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bundesliga_records_and_statistics&oldid=931532256#Runs_2)), [Football records and statistics in Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_records_and_statistics_in_Spain#Individual_records) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Football_records_and_statistics_in_Spain&oldid=931365459#Individual_records)), [Premier League records and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League_records_and_statistics#Goals_2) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Premier_League_records_and_statistics&oldid=930866013#Goals_2)), [Football records and statistics in Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_records_and_statistics_in_Italy#Goalscoring) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Football_records_and_statistics_in_Italy&oldid=931594372#Goalscoring)), [List of Ligue 1 records and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ligue_1_records_and_statistics#Goalscoring) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Ligue_1_records_and_statistics&oldid=893480503#Goalscoring))
- UEFA: [Longest goalscoring runs in Europe's top leagues](https://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/news/newsid=2062223.html) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190424083224/https://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/news/newsid=2062223.html)) (November 2015)
- BBC: [Jamie Vardy breaks record for goals in consecutive games](https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/34953098) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20191212140704/https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/34953098)) (November 2015)
- Bleacher Report: [Chronicling Records That Neymar and Kylian Mbappe Could Break This Season](https://bleacherreport.com/articles/2733786-chronicling-records-that-neymar-and-kylian-mbappe-could-break-this-season) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20191222081942/https://bleacherreport.com/articles/2733786-chronicling-records-that-neymar-and-kylian-mbappe-could-break-this-season)) (September 2017)
- [The longest ever goalscoring runs in the major European leagues](https://www.besoccer.com/new/the-longest-ever-goalscoring-runs-in-the-major-european-leagues-314482) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20171226072950/http://www.besoccer.com/new/the-longest-ever-goalscoring-runs-in-the-major-european-leagues-314482)) (October 2017)

Comment: The answer is [community wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info), feel free to update it or add further sources, if needed.